# Create and active Directory Account with no priviliges

Tags: authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I want to know if it's possible to create an Active Directory user account that confers no access or privileges to that user.. simply to authenticate a set of credentials..
As we are hybridised AD/Azure organisation, I want this 'account' to replicate to Azure through the connector.

The reason for this is that:

1. We manage all our users through AD so I don't want some accounts managed only in Azure.. it would be very confusing. Centralised managemnent and support is good!
2. The account would ONLY be used for authenticating users into Zoom via SAML2, or any another cloud service for that matter that can use Azure as an authentication service.
3. No capacity to access anything within our firewall.

Your ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Gus

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the most basic permissions that any user is created can also view other users or groups in AAD. If you want to turn off this basic permission, just set `Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal` to `Yes`, then the user will not have any access rights.

Go to azure portal->click Azure Active Direcotory->User settings

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you define "access". By default, the Authenticated Users group is able to read everything in AD, but not write. If you're ok with that, then you're done. Just create a user and don't *add* any access to it.

If you don't want it to read anything on the domain, then you'll have trouble. The Authenticated Users group is [described as](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems):

> A group that includes all users whose identities were authenticated when they logged on. Membership is controlled by the operating system.

Since there is no way to *not* have a user be part of Authenticated Users, then you would have to modify the permissions on your domain to exclude Authenticated Users. But that may cause other issues for other users.